# Зачем внутри функции присваивать переменной значение this?

Tags: javascript, функции, оператор-присваивания

Недавно искал способы удаления/замены подстроки в JS. Наткнулся на вот такой пример кастомной функции удаления:

```
String.prototype.removeWord = function(searchWord){
var str = this;
var n = str.search(searchWord);
while(str.search(searchWord) > -1){
    n = str.search(searchWord);
    str = str.substring(0, n) + str.substring(n + searchTerm.length, str.length);
}

return str;
```

Потому как JS я начал изучать недавно у меня возник вопрос: что происходит в строке

`var str = this;`

Зачем нужно такого рода присваивание и что оно собственно помещает в переменную `str`? Спасибо.

Comment: можно не присваивать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это присваивание помещает в переменную `str` ссылку на строку, чей метод выполняется. Таким образом задается начальное значение строки, изменяющейся в итерационном процессе удаления.

Answer (score 0):

**В данном случае** такого рода присваивания **можно делать** для того, чтобы сократить количество кода, **либо же** для того, чтобы **не** изменять значение `this`.

**В других случаях** такое присваивание внутри функции делается для замыкания, о котором написано **[тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)**.